# How to change drop down direction with selectize?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using AgularJs Selectize plugin, in [docs](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md)  have posibility to change dropdown direction, but i can't realize how it works... Maybe somewho also using this plugin and can tell me how to change drop down direction from bot to up?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution from members on github, add this part of code to your controller file:

```
 if (!window.Selectize.prototype.positionDropdownOriginal) {
      window.Selectize.prototype.positionDropdownOriginal = window.Selectize.prototype.positionDropdown;
      window.Selectize.prototype.positionDropdown = function () {
          if (this.settings.dropdownDirection === 'up') {
              let $control = this.$control;
              let offset = this.settings.dropdownParent === 'body' ? $control.offset() : $control.position();
  
              this.$dropdown.css({
                  width: $control.outerWidth(),
                  left: offset.left,
                  bottom: 'calc(100% + 4px)'
              });
              this.$dropdown.addClass('direction-' + this.settings.dropdownDirection);
              this.$control.addClass('direction-' + this.settings.dropdownDirection);
              this.$wrapper.addClass('direction-' + this.settings.dropdownDirection);
          } else {
              window.Selectize.prototype.positionDropdownOriginal.apply(this, arguments);
          }
      };
    }
```

My config object is:

```
 vm.config = {
      delimiter: ',',
      persist: false,
      plugins: ['remove_button' ],
      create: false,
      dropdownDirection: 'up'  <= also add this part
    };
```

And it works perfect, thanks to guys from this [topic](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/issues/29)